# Good, free isometric game engine?

Tags: isometric

Any recommendations for a good isometric game engine that is also free?

1. Should be possible to develop entirely using freely available tools (meaning: no Flash, and no I don't want to learn haXe...)
2. Works-in-a-browser is a plus, but not required.
3. Support for 32-bit images is required!
4. Good performance.
5. Excellent documentation.

I have looked at FIFE but it is still too unfinished, and the documentation sucks!

Comment: FYI: You can develop flash-games using only freely available tools: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/325/how-can-i-develop-flash-games-without-expensive-software

Comment: The page you linked to talks a lot about haXe. Is there a non-haXe free Flash development solution?

Comment: Yes, http://www.flashdevelop.org/ + Flex SDK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created games using [as3isolib](http://code.google.com/p/as3isolib/) and it works really great for me. It is library for actionscript 3.0 (flash), and as bummzack said in comment, you can develop flash games using only free tools.

Comment: question states "no flash"

Comment: Only because the he thinks developing in flash is not free, but in reality Adobe offers the FLEX compiler for free, and you do not need to use flash to create assets.

Comment: The as3isolib library looks nice. Which free tools are you referring to?

Comment: Flex includes [a free command line compiler](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Downloads) for compiling Actionscript into SWF (Flash). Haxe is also free and can produce SWF. What Adobe charges for is their IDE, but you can use Flashdevelop or Emacs/Vim/Sublime instead.

Answer (score 2):

There's always [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) for everything. ;D
It supports browsers, performs excellently, and has good documentation. You could use the orthographic camera for isometric easily.

Comment: And it is super-not-isometric

Comment: 'You could use the orthographic camera for isometric easily.'.

Comment: It's still not an isometric engine :)

Comment: Yeah, Unity3D is really lacking on the whole "isometric" part. It is, however, finished and reasonably well-documented. No real isometric engine can boast of that (-8

Comment: Not all browsers are supported. Be aware that the unity plugin is not available for a significant part of your target audience.

Comment: I looked at Unity3D previously when I was considering a different, real-time 3D project. Is it useful at all for me though?

Comment: Unity 3d is not for making isometric games.

Comment: @Vish using that argument, C++ isn't for isometric games either. Neither is SDL, or most other graphics libraries. It fits all his requirements well, and just requires him to do a very small amount of work setting up the tiles.

Comment: @The Communist Duck: hmmm, I've just used unity for trying out some demo 3d using javascript, I didn't find anything related to isometric in it, sorry.

Comment: @Vish I've just tried out SDL and didn't find anything related to isometric in it either. Doesn't make it any less of a good option.

Comment: @The Communist Duck: :))